# GET_AUTHORIZATION_URL_ERROR in next-auth while using keycloak

Tags: next.js, keycloak, next-auth

I am trying a demo on keycloak with next-auth with the help of demo from the official site.
But it's not working as expected. Application is navigating to keycloak sign in page, but when clicked on sign in button it's redirecting to `localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?error=OauthSignin` and there is an error in terminal that `only absolute URL's can be requested`.

Below is the code in `[...nextauth.js]`

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import KeycloakProvider from 'next-auth/providers/keycloak'

export default NextAuth ({
    providers: [
        KeycloakProvider({
            "realm": Users,
            "auth-server-url": 'http://localhost:8080/auth/',
            'ssl-required': 'external',
            'resource': 'Route',
            'public-client': true,
            'confidential-port': 0
        })
    ]
})
```

Please mention if any additional settings required to configure keycloak in Next.js using next-auth.

Comment: Did you set redirect_uri?

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. Issues is resolved now. Added clientId and issuer as per next-auth documentation.